# htaccess rewriting to wrong page

Tags: web-services, .htaccess, web

I have begun learning htaccess and i'm massively struggling.  I'm simply trying to remove my .php from a URL

subdomain.example.com/weddings.php

to

subdomain.example.com/weddings/

to be honest that's not entirely it. the full url is

subdomain.example.com/weddings.php?section=pyromusicals#divname

which im trying to make into

subdomain.example.com/weddings/divname

for now though just the removal of the .php to / would be helpful.

so far I have in my htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*).php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,QSA]
```

which is re-writing to

subdomain.example.co.uk/wedding-fireworks/

which is great but it also generates a 404 error page not found.

The requested URL /wedding-fireworks/index was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are wanting to do?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?section=pyromusicals#$2 [QSA,L]     
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Note that is assuming your `section` will always = `pyromusicals`

If section changes, you will need to include it in your URL also example below.

```
http://www.yoursite.com/somephppage/nameofsection/divname
```

Then your mod rewrite would look like this.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1.php?section=$2#$3 [QSA,L]     
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Im affriad then generates an 500 internal page error when I turn it on.  My site is a subdomain.  does that matter?  Links are route relative though    http://subdomain.mysite.co.uk/weddings.php?section=just-fireworks#just-fireworks